# How to change the spell checking language in Chromium?

Tags: chromium, spell-check

When write I need spell checking in Danish or English (one at a time, not both at the same time), but changing from one language to the other is not working well for me.

*Example:* Writing an email in English, everything is underlined as misspelled because the spelling language is set to Danish. I then right-click the text field and choose "Spell-checker Options" and set the language to English. But is does not change the language. Only after I try maybe 4-5 times it does.

Selecting the text, clicking it, clicking the background, click the text, I have tried it all but I cannot figure out how it works. Sometimes it changes on first try, sometimes I have to do it 6-7 times.

Searching brings lots of a known bugs stating that Chromium does not re-check the text after changing the language. But that is not what drives me crazy, for starters being able to change the language in the first try would be nice.

It is not a fault in my installation, I have the same problem on 3 computers. Does any know something that I don't?

Comment: It looks like there were plans to add an [adaptive spelling-checker](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/7fJpblxAQWU) to Chrome/ium but the concept doesn't appear to have gained enough traction (desværre!).

Answer (score 2):

In a Text Area, right-click and select language in 'Spell-checker options'.

*New* text is correctly checked, while *old* text not.

What I do is:

1. Select all text
2. Cut it
3. Paste it at the same Text Area

Then all text inserted is *new* and correctly checked in the selected language.

Comment: Ctrl+A X V actually does not work for me (Chrome, Linux). What does work is simply letting the cursor wander over all the words, so I do Ctrl+Home and then hold Ctrl+Right to traverse the message. It is quickly done, even for quite long messages, if it should be needed. If your method works it is of course even snappier.

Comment: Sorry, I presumably always checked a correct spelled text. You are perfectly right @DanielAndersson, when checking an incorrect text, mistakes are not underlined until you pass with cursor.